# I am looking for a JSON Path expression that will point to the node that contains the value [invalid field]

Tags: json

I am looking for a JSON Path expression that will point to '[invalid field]'. I don't want to make it specific to this example, as the top level node will change.

```
{"orderDetails": {
   "paymentDate": "10/30/2015 3:22:57 PM",
   "billingDetails":    {
      "name1": "john doe",
      "name2": "[invalid field]",
      "billingAddress":       {
         "street1": "1234 easy street",
         "street2": "[invalid field]",
         "city": "San Jose",
         "state": "CA",
         "zip": "90404",
         "country": "USA"
      }
   }
}}
```

Comment: I attempted this: $..[@.=="[invalid field]"], but could not get it to resolve correctly